# Efficient algorithm for determinant of a m-diagonal NxN symmetric matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, sparse-matrix, determinants

I have to find the determinant of a symmetric square NxN matrix with M diagonals and `M << N`. Is there a more fast method than LU-decomposing the matrix?

Comment: Is it positive definite as well?

Comment: @Harmen no, but it is real if this matters

Comment: aren't row reductions to a lower (or upper) diagonal matrix going to be pretty efficient here as you can ignore all the zeros and do far fewer operations?

Comment: @TooTone for a single calculation yes but I have to calculate a lot of such determinants. I am almost new to these arguments so I am only asking if the LU decomposition is the fastest way or if there exist faster methods

Comment: @Red to be honest if it were me, I'd work through some examples and see if I could find a general formula. When I had to do something similar, I found [this](http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/determ1/determ1.html) useful. Finally as your question has no code, you might find it better to ask on math.se if there is a general formula, perhaps with a simple motivating example, and then come back here with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are special methods for band(ed) matrices that solve elimination with O(N*M^2) complexity. Arbitrary found [article of Jeff Thorson](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/oldreports/sep20/20_11.pdf)